# Pip installed a module I want to use, but still getting "module not found" error

Tags: python, module, pip

I am trying to use the Python module Gdal. I have run `pip install gdal` and I recieve the message

```
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in c:\users\willy\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.3.1)
```

and yet when I run `import gdal` in my Python IDE (I use Spyder), I still get the error `no module named gdal`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Spyder which Python interpreter to use. Point it to the one you're installing the package for, as it seems that it's using a different one.

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: The python installer that you used may have set environment not detected by spyder.  Try open a command prompt and print environment variable %PATH% (assume you are using windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it seems you have to call:

`from osgeo import gdal`

See [here](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html)

Answer (score -1):

Answer is here in Spyder docs: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Don't try to use pip install and expect it to work in Spyder. Follow these instructions